# How to find bases for $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}^3$ so that $\overline{A}$ is the matrix associated to $f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

I need to find a new pair of bases for $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}^3$ so that the linear transformation $f:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^3$, defined as $f(x,y)=(ix,x+iy,y)$, is represented by the following matrix:

$$\overline{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Without knowing what you've tried and where you've failed, it is hard to provide good answers. If you give us a better idea of how much you understand this problem you will have answers better suited for your level of understanding. Please [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) to improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\bigl((1,0),(0,1)\bigr)$ as a basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$. Then $f(1,0)=(i,1,0)$ and $f(0,1)=(0,i,1)$. Choose *any* vector $v\in\mathbb{C}^3$ such that $(i,1,0)$, $(0,i,1)$ and $v$ are linearly independent and take $\bigl((i,1,0),(0,i,1),v\bigr)$ as a basis of $\mathbb{C}^3$.